# Pandas: iterate over rows in grouped data and based on if else condition perform some operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped data-frame of the following format:

```
     TC      lbl     date 
101  101       f      28-12-2017
     101       f      27-08-2019
     101       m      12-04-2013
     101       m      25-06-2015
     101       f      16-08-2016

102  102       m      15-08-2019
     102       m      25-06-2019
```

say, for the group 101, iterate through column ['lbl']

```
for (columnName, columnData) in r.iteritems():
    if ['lbl'][i]==['lbl'][i+1] & ['lbl'][i+1]=='f':
        r.diff(['date'][i],['date'][i+1])=['date'][i+1]
    elif ['lbl'][i]==['lbl'][i+1] & ['lbl'][i+1]!='f':
        ['date'][i+1]=['date'][i+1]
    elif ['lbl'][i]!=['lbl'][i+1] & ['lbl'][i+1]=='f':
        r.diff(['date'][i],['date'][i+1])=['date'][i+1]
    else:
        if ['lbl'][i]!=['lbl'][i+1] & ['lbl'][i+1]!='f':
            ['date'][i+1]=['date'][i+1]
```

The operations need to be done inside the groups itself,ie,there needs to be no interaction between successive groups even if ['lbl'] is changing. is that possible?

The output dataframe needs to be:

```
          TC      lbl     date 
 101     101       f      28-12-2017
         101       f      607 days
         101       m      12-04-2013
         101       m      25-06-2015
         101       f      418 days
 102     102       m      15-08-2019
         102       m      25-06-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[[101,'f',datetime.date(2017,12,28)],
                         [101, 'f', datetime.date(2019,8,27)],
                         [101,'m',datetime.date(2013,4,12)],
                         [101,'m',datetime.date(2015,6,25)],
                         [101, 'f', datetime.date(2016,8,16)],
                         [102,'m', datetime.date(2019,8,15)],
                         [102,'m',datetime.date(2019,6,25)]],
                  columns=["TC", "lbl", "date"])

for i in data.index[1:]:
    if (data.at[i, 'lbl'] == data.at[i-1, 'lbl']) & (data.at[i, 'lbl'] == 'f'):
        data.at[i, 'date'] = data.at[i, 'date'] - data.at[i-1, 'date']
    elif data.at[i, 'lbl'] == 'f':
        data.at[i, 'date'] = data.at[i, 'date'] - data.at[i-1, 'date']
```

Now data is:

```
        TC    lbl                   date 
0      101      f             2017-12-28
1      101      f      607 days, 0:00:00
2      101      m             2013-04-12
3      101      m             2015-06-25
4      101      f      418 days, 0:00:00
5      102      m             2019-08-15
6      102      m             2019-06-25
```

EDIT:
This works for a DataFrame with a MultiIndex

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(101,101), (101,101), (101,101), (101,101), (101, 101), (102, 102), (102, 102)], names=[None, "TC"])
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[['f',datetime.date(2017,12,28)],
                          ['f', datetime.date(2019,8,27)],
                          ['m',datetime.date(2013,4,12)],
                          ['m',datetime.date(2015,6,25)],
                          ['f', datetime.date(2016,8,16)],
                          ['m', datetime.date(2019,8,15)],
                          ['m',datetime.date(2019,6,25)]],
                    index = index,
                    columns=["lbl", "date"])

for i, t in enumerate(data.index):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    if (data.iat[i, 0] == data.iat[i-1, 0]) & (data.iat[i, 0]=='f'):
        data.iat[i, 1] = data.iat[i, 1] - data.iat[i-1, 1]
    elif data.iat[i, 0] == 'f':
        data.iat[i, 1] = data.iat[i, 1] - data.iat[i-1, 1]
```

Comment: error unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'   will  data.index[1:] work if my data is grouped?  my actual dataframe is of this format  https://imgur.com/a/CuszTjX

Comment: if i dont group the data   https://imgur.com/a/fp2hKZe   and run your algo the following error occurs :
cannot set a Timestamp with a non-timestamp.is that  because in some row of 'date' column there might be a NON-TIMESTAMP data?

Comment: Note: In my edit I've used `iat` with column numbers i.e. 0 for `lbl` and 1 for `date`

Comment: Thanks, but when i initialize your example multi-index dataframe the following error pops up   ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 2), indices imply (1, 2)

for the first  https://imgur.com/a/fp2hKZe dataframe type though, i dont understand what is up with this error ValueError: cannot set a Timestamp with a non-timestamp

Comment: and if i run your multi-index algo on my real dataset, it dosent actually do anything , ie for (f after f  'lbl') and (f after m 'lbl')

Comment: My example copy-pasted works for me. What line are you getting the error on?
And can you maybe send me a sample of your dataset so I can test what works for it?

Comment: im getting the error on line   r.at[i, 'date'] = r.at[i, 'date'] - r.at[i-1, 'date']   if im applying it to the single index sorted dataframe   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jduZfsIpElpuFcuZXaKrPAG8mrx_-wWi

Comment: I understood the error was occurring because i was overlooking the datatype of my actual data-set. the dtype for my actual date column was datetime64. impeccably stupid of me.

Comment: but if i convert the datatype for the date column using ``strftime``  the algo wont be able to substract the values in the first place..

Comment: so itd be simpler if i save the timedelta value into a new column ?

Comment: Afaik, `datetime64` should support subtraction. Otherwise you can also try `pd.to_datetime(date1)-pd.to_datetime(date2)` where `date1` and `date2` are in datetime64 format. `strftime` won't work - it converts dates to strings!